# How to update Shopify cart on new item added

Tags: jquery, ajax, shopify, liquid

I added the cart to all pages. Now I want it to automatically update, when the user clicks on the add to cart button of an item. It works with a delayed refresh (really dirty:/), but there has to be a better option. I would be happy if I can get some answers:)

Comment: you can look deeper into the `narrative` free theme from shopify. It is using ajax to update the cart.

Comment: use Shopify AJAX cart API [Link](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/ajax-api/reference/cart) to perform various actions without leaving the page.